# How to solve this probability problem? (leaving only white balls)

Tags: probability

There is a vase containing

n white balls

m black balls.

Randomly taking out balls, without putting them back inside, 
i need to show that the probability that only white balls are left is $$\frac{n}{n+m}$$

I have tried to use the formula
$$P(A) = \sum_{a=0}^nP(A|B)*P(B)$$

using

A = only white left

B = M black balls were draws and X white balls were drawn

but this leads to a too complicated compution, of $P(A) = \sum_{x=0}^n\frac{(m+x)!(m+x)!}{(m+n)!(n-x)!}$

I think there must be an easier and more intelligent way to solve this, but im new to the subject and feeling abit lost.. 
any kind of help, advice, hints or full solutions will be great!

Thanks guys!

Comment: What are $m$ and $n$? How many balls are you going to take out?

Comment: The number of total balls in the vase

Comment: So $m$ and $n$ are the same as $M$ and $N$? OK. But what do you mean, "only white balls are left"? If you take out all the balls, there will be **no** balls left. Do you mean, you keep taking balls out until only balls of one color are left? In other words, you want the probability that the **last** ball in the vase is white? Of **course** that probability is $N/(M+N)$, the same as the probability that the **first** ball drawn is white.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you keep taking balls out until the remainder are all the same colour.
If you end up with only white balls in the urn, the last ball you take out will be white.
If the last ball you take out is white, then when the balls are all the same colour, they will all be white.
So the chances are the same as just the colour of the last ball, which is white $n/(n+m)$ of the time.